# Does (display) mean that the card is not fully utilized for Cycles rendering?

Tags: gpu, hardware

My GTX 1070 card shows as (display) in Preferences>System even though I use the integrated video for the monitor.

[image]

Does the (display) designation mean that the card is not fully utilized for Cycles rendering? How can I make it not "display" and is it even worth it?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just think it means it is currently used to drive a display, or draw Blender UI.

Comment: Yes, but does that mean that the card is not utilized 100% for Cycles rendering?

Comment: No, I don't think it has any implications on what amount of resources are used for rendering. As far as I know rendering uses all available resources for rendering, at the expense of screen refresh rate, I think

Comment: Thanks Duarte. In that case I guess getting an extra GPU just for display won't be very useful.

Comment: An extra GPU just for display is not very useful, unless you multitask a lot and use your PC for other activities while rendering. An additional rendering GPU however will virtually double rendering speed and is very worthwhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculating and refreshing all the pixels on the screen(s) is the main job of a GPU and this requires a significant amount of resources, which will be scarce when the GPU is used for rendering as well.

So if you want your display to be responsive while GPU-rendering, then it's a good idea to reserve one GPU just for its originally intended job of of pushing those pixels to the display(s).

The '(Display)' text from the CUDA settings helps you accomplish this, by indicating which of your GPUs is currently connected to the display(s).
Otherwise you wouldn't be able to tell which one is which if you had say 3 x GTX 1070.